# MyLocation cannot be cast to com.example.mycoordinate.TaskLoadedCallback

Tags: android

MyLocation.Java

```
package com.example.mycoordinate;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;

public class MyLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    private MarkerOptions place1, place2;

    //getLocation()
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String locationText = "";
    String locationLatitude = "";
    String locationLongitude = "";

    private Handler mHandler ;
    private int mInterval = 3000; // after the coordinate is found, refresh every 3 seconds.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps_offline);
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        //Alert Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MyLocation.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog2.setTitle("Notification");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        String string1 = "Give it 10-15 seconds for your coordinates to update. Keep moving around and you will see coordinates update.";

        alertDialog2.setMessage(string1);

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Btn
//        alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("Continue",
//                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//
//                    }
//                });

        // Showing Alert Dialog
        alertDialog2.show();

        Handler handler2 = new Handler();
        handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mHandler = new Handler();
                startRepeatingTask();
            }
        }, 1000);   //5 seconds

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopRepeatingTask();
    }

    Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final EditText yourlat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourLat);
            final EditText yourlong = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourLong);

            try {
                getLocation(); //this function can change value of mInterval.

                if (locationText.toString() == "") {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Locating us...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    yourlat.setText(locationLatitude.toString());
                    yourlong.setText(locationLongitude.toString());
                }
            } finally {

                mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
            }
        }
    };

    void startRepeatingTask() {
        mStatusChecker.run();
    }

    void stopRepeatingTask() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    }

    void getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 5, (LocationListener) this);
        }
        catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        locationText = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
        locationLatitude = location.getLatitude() + "";
        locationLongitude = location.getLongitude() + "";
        final LatLng home = new LatLng(1.363451, 103.834337); //HOME
        final LatLng current = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); //current position
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
//                double zoomLevel = googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
//                if (zoomLevel < 8) {
//                    zoomLevel = 18.0;
//                }
//                googleMap.clear();
                //googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current_position).title("Current Location"));
                //googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(current_position) );
                //googleMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( (float) zoomLevel) );
                //googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title("Home"));
                //googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place1.getPosition()) );

                place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(current).title("Current");
                place2 = new MarkerOptions().position(home).title("Home");
                googleMap.addMarker(place1);
                googleMap.addMarker(place2);

                //Route between two points
                new FetchURL(MyLocation.this).execute(getUrl(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition(), "driving"), "driving" );

                //distance between two points in a Straight Line
                Double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition());
                CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                        .target(place1.getPosition())
                        .zoom(16)
                        .bearing(0)
                        //.tilt(45)
                        .build();

                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 10000, null);

                Log.d("Location", "Distance: " + distance );
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(MyLocation.this, "Please Enable GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest, String directionMode) {
        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
        // Mode
        String mode = "mode=" + directionMode;
        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + mode;
        // Output format
        String output = "json";
        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters + "&key=" + getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
        Log.d("TEST", "getUrl: " + url);
        return url;
    }


}
```

FetchURL.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;



public class FetchURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context mContext;
    String directionMode = "driving";

    public FetchURL(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";
        directionMode = strings[1];
        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(strings[0]);
            Log.d("mylog", "Background task data " + data.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        PointsParser parserTask = new PointsParser(mContext, directionMode);
        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(s);
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();
            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            Log.d("mylog", "Downloaded URL: " + data.toString());
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("mylog", "Exception downloading URL: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

PointsParser.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class PointsParser extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    TaskLoadedCallback taskCallback;
    String directionMode = "driving";

    public PointsParser(Context mContext, String directionMode) {
        this.taskCallback = (TaskLoadedCallback) mContext;  <---- this is the error
        this.directionMode = directionMode;
    }

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            Log.d("mylog", jsonData[0].toString());
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            Log.d("mylog", parser.toString());

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            Log.d("mylog", "Executing routes");
            Log.d("mylog", routes.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("mylog", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            if (directionMode.equalsIgnoreCase("walking")) {
                lineOptions.width(10);
                lineOptions.color(Color.MAGENTA);
            } else {
                lineOptions.width(20);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }
            Log.d("mylog", "onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if (lineOptions != null) {
            //mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            taskCallback.onTaskDone(lineOptions);

        } else {
            Log.d("mylog", "without Polylines drawn");
        }

        taskCallback.onTaskDone();
    }
}
```

TaskLoadedCallback.java

```
public interface TaskLoadedCallback {
    void onTaskDone(Object... values);
}
```

It has been almost a week trying to understand and trying to fix this the error Below.

```
2019-08-12 14:29:01.822 14672-14672/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-08-12 14:29:01.824 14672-14672/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-08-12 14:29:01.866 14672-14680/? E/le.mycoordinat: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
2019-08-12 14:29:03.831 14672-14672/com.example.mycoordinate E/ViewRootImpl@c1f726b[MyLocation]: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=true mPausedForTransition=false
2019-08-12 14:29:03.859 14672-14672/com.example.mycoordinate E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
2019-08-12 14:29:07.662 14672-14672/com.example.mycoordinate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mycoordinate, PID: 14672
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mycoordinate.MyLocation cannot be cast to com.example.mycoordinate.TaskLoadedCallback
        at com.example.mycoordinate.PointsParser.<init>(PointsParser.java:20)
        at com.example.mycoordinate.FetchURL.onPostExecute(FetchURL.java:44)
        at com.example.mycoordinate.FetchURL.onPostExecute(FetchURL.java:18)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Any kindhearted individual who can help me with this? It has been almost a week since i started this journey.  I already passed (MyLocation.this - as reference to the activity) but it still doesnt work... do note my Google API is working fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are passing `MyLocation` to PointsParser and try to cast it to `TaskLoadedCallback` in `this.taskCallback = (TaskLoadedCallback) mContext;`, add TaskLoadedCallback to implements in `MyLocation`

```
public class MyLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, TaskLoadedCallback {
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: boss on PointsParser.java how do i approach this line: mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);  since mMap was not passed to the class as googleMap.

Comment: yes i will definitely read that link and understand... anyway, i pass my googleMap to fetchUrl, then pass to PointsParser  it works now... but i still have no idea how this callback works... thank you for your replay...